# Do something with SHOW COLUMNS result?

Tags: mysql, sql, metadata

Is is possible to do something with result of SHOW COLUMNS query?

For example add resulted rows to some table of select against it?

The following doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM (SHOW COLUMNS FROM MyTable )
```

**UPDATE**

So, `SHOW COLUMNS` is a thing in itself?

Comment: Please exemplify your use case. It's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve column information as a *resultset* in SQL that you can manipulate, use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='database-name' AND TABLE_NAME='table-name';
```

You can do something with the results of `SHOW` statements, but not using SQL. `SHOW` statements are not part of ANSI SQL, they're an *extension* in MySQL. Note this comment from [SHOW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show.html) documentation:

> Many MySQL APIs (such as PHP) enable you to treat the result returned from a SHOW statement as you would a result set from a SELECT; see Chapter 25, Connectors and APIs, or your API documentation for more information.
>
> In addition, you can work in SQL with results from queries on tables in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database, which you cannot easily do with results from SHOW statements. See Chapter 22, INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables.

`SHOW` statements are more for a Database Administrator to quickly retrieve metadata regarding database structure. That said, 'under-the-hood' I would assume it queries the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` but formats the output to be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You cant work with data using `SHOW COLUMNS` AFAIK, it more displays the information about the columns. Datatype etc.

You can use a syntax like this work with the data.

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase' AND TABLE_NAME='table';;
```

Comment: Is there any reason for being unable to work with `SHOW TABLES` or this is just bad design?

Comment: @Dims "bad design" would be for an RDBMS to allow implicit conversions between data and representation/implementation details. Besides, define "work with". What are you actually trying to do?